# How to get current branch name in Bamboo using Java Api

Tags: java, api, bamboo

I've created project using:

```
atlas-create-bamboo-plugin
```

And I need to get current branch name using Java Api.
I need something like:

```
@Override
    public TaskResult execute(final TaskContext taskContext) throws TaskException {
        final BuildLogger buildLogger = taskContext.getBuildLogger();
        buildLogger.addBuildLogEntry("BranchName: " + /*Some magic*/);

        return TaskResultBuilder.newBuilder(taskContext).success().build();
    }
```

Comment: Simply googling "bamboo java api" leads to the official documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject a variable context into your task and get access to must build and deploy variables. It works like Spring bean injection, if you are familiar with Spring.

```
@Scanned
public class YourTask implements CommonTaskType {

    private final CustomVariableContext customVariableContext;

    public YourTask(@ComponentImport CustomVariableContext customVariableContext) {
        this.customVariableContext = customVariableContext;
    }

    @Override
    public TaskResult execute(@NotNull CommonTaskContext taskContext) throws TaskException {
        final TaskResultBuilder taskResultBuilder = TaskResultBuilder.newBuilder(taskContext);
        final BuildLogger buildLogger = taskContext.getBuildLogger();

        Map<String, String> buildVariables = customVariableContext.getVariables(taskContext.getCommonContext());

        // get branch name from build variables
        String branchName = buildVariables.get("planRepository.branchName");

        // log all build variables to console
        buildVariables.forEach((key, value) -> buildLogger.addBuildLogEntry(key + ": " + value));

        return taskResultBuilder.success().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! One more question: wich class need to be injected to get commit information in current branch? Or even can you please provide link to documentation for classes that can be injected?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get commit information just by injecting a manager, but it's possible to generate them as part of a deployment.
I have not been able to find a complete list of injectable managers, but some info can be found here: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/accessing-bamboo-components-from-plugin-modules/

Comment: Besides those mentioned in the link in my previous comment, I know of these beans that can be injected:

- I18nBeanFactory // Language management, can be used to handle language specif texts
- ProcessService processService // Process management, handlings bamboo processes
- ArtifactManager artifactManager // Artifact management, can create artifacts
- CredentialsManager credentialsManager // Credential management, can be used to retrive bamboo shared credentials